# using strings from a header row as "pointers"

Tags: core-language

Suppose I have a list like:

```
data={{"product","amount","price"},{"A",1,100},{"A",3,100},{"B",5,200}}
```

I could use a Map to calculate over each row the "amount" * "price"
easily like

```
Map[#[[2]] #[[3]] &, data[[2 ;;]]]
```

But I would prefer to write something like

```
Map["amount" "price"&, data[[2;;]]]
```

This would be convenient because sometimes the columns are shifted in another order. I tried to work with Rules but the evaluation order is a problem.
Is there a way to do this?
When I use

```
r = Thread[Rule[{"product", "amount", "price"}, Range@3]]
```

I could use

```
Map[(#[["amount"]] #[["price"]] /. r) &, data[[2 ;;]]]
```

It works with a complaint about the part specification

```
Map[(#[["amount"/.r]] #[["price"/.r]]) &, data[[2 ;;]]]
```

works but is not much better then hard coded numbers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `new = AssociationThread[First@data -> #] & /@ Rest[data]; new[[All, {"product", "price"}]] // Values`?

Comment: @Kuba thx but that doesn't do the multiplication of amount and price right?

Comment: You can do whatever query you want once you have a list of associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
assoc = AssociationThread[data[[1]] -> #] & /@ data[[2 ;;]];
Map[#amount #price &]@assoc
```

> {100, 300, 1000}

Comment: o wow I completely forgot about the slotnames stuff. Great!